# Svn checkout has no response in the docker image of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, svn

I ran the following command, it seems to be stuck, neither error nor success：

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:22.04 /bin/bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y subversion && svn co https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF/trunk/amf/public/include --non-interactive amf-headers"
```

also I tried debug log,still no output:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:22.04 /bin/bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y subversion && svn co https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF/trunk/amf/public/include --non-interactive --config-option servers:global:neon-debug-mask=1073741824 amf-headers"
```

so I tried ubuntu 20.04 and it at least gives an error:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq subversion && svn co https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF/trunk/amf/public/include --non-interactive amf-headers"

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF/trunk/amf/public/include'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted
```

Why does svn have no response on Ubuntu 22.04?

If it is an ssl certificate problem like ubuntu 20.04, it should also give an error message instead of nothing

more detail：

GitHub repositories can be accessed from both Git and Subversion (SVN) clients [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/working-with-subversion-on-github/support-for-subversion-clients)

I do all the test with github action(ubuntu-latest/ubuntu-20.04),[Included Software](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md)

- Docker Compose v1 1.29.2
- Docker Compose v2 2.1.1+azure-1
- Docker-Buildx 0.7.0
- Docker-Moby Client 20.10.11+azure-1
- Docker-Moby
  Server 20.10.11+azure-1

test workflow:

```
name: Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  Test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        version: ["22.04", "21.10", "21.04", "20.04"]

    steps:
      - name: Test
        timeout-minutes: 5
        shell: bash
        run: |
          docker run --rm ubuntu:${{ matrix.version }} /bin/bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq subversion && svn co https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF/trunk/amf/public/include --non-interactive amf-headers"
```

***If you really want konw where I used this command,you can try using https://github.com/shinchiro/mpv-winbuild-cmake to build mpv with docker image ubuntu:22.04.The toolchain use svn to download some files.***

Comment: Why do you expect a Github repository to be accessible over Subversion?

Comment: @tripleee GitHub repositories can be accessed from both Git and Subversion (SVN) clients [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/working-with-subversion-on-github/support-for-subversion-clients).And I only need part of this repo,so I choice svn

Comment: @tripleee In fact, a compilation toolchain I used uses svn to download parts of GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF as "amf-headers".When using the toolchain to compile something yesterday, this problem caused the entire compilation to fail.

Comment: Why are you running this in a temporary container, where the checkout will be lost as soon as the container exits?  Could you put this logic into a reusable Dockerfile instead?  In the last case, does installing the [`ca-certificates`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ca-certificates) package help?

Comment: @DavidMaze "apt-get install -y ca-certificates" still does not solve the problem.I explained in the previous comment that this is actually just a command that I found a problem during compilation, not all of it. A command specially selected for the convenience of discussion or recurrence of the problem.The real question is why svn checkout is not working, not why it is used

Comment: @DavidMaze If you really want konw where I used this command,you can try using https://github.com/shinchiro/mpv-winbuild-cmake to build mpv with docker image ubuntu:22.04.The toolchain use svn to download some files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in current Ubuntu 22.04 development version filed as [bug #1959717](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/1959717) - I guess we have to wait until it gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have reported it to Subversion,but no developer confirm this is a bug

Comment: I don't think it's a subversion bug because I use same subversion release with other distros without problem. Seems to be a Ubuntu 22.04 bug though.